# Make a side bar like Dolphin browser or Firefox in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I would like to create a sidebar like the one in dolphin browser or firefox for android.

I have a listview that is my main screen, when I swype to right I wish to move the listview to right and make appear a new view on the left.

Like [this](http://bestmobileapp.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Dolphin-Browser-HD-Android.jpg)

Thanks

PS : I'm a french guy sorry for the english :-)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`Workspace` widget in the Android Open Source Project Launcher2 code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/launcher2/Workspace.java;h=d19344857a9b7eb9476e7d4b60262b52b49b7f2e;hb=HEAD). This is the widget that implements the side to side paging behavior on the stock Android home screen.

The basic idea is to create a custom widget that can pan its contents with rules for snapping to a final position if the user flings or lets go. Use `onInterceptTouchEvent` to determine when the user has crossed a 'slop' threshold in horizontal motion (you can get the system values for this from [`ViewConfiguration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html)) and steal away input focus from any child views in the hierarchy. From there, control the panning in `onTouchEvent`. You can use a [`VelocityTracker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/VelocityTracker.html) to determine how the content should fling when the user lets go and a [`Scroller`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html) to help you animate to the final position.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) supported by the [Support-V4 package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), you can put `Fragments` in it, one for your main screen, and another for your sidebar, and then the user can swipe to see the hidden sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the pane with LinearLayout with a width at 0, then you can use also GestureBuilder to detect horizontal swipe and Animation to change progressively the widthof your LinearLayout to the desired width.